# How do I make JQuery UI Slider update Meteor Collection (MongoDB) without disappearing

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor

I have two Meteor.Collections in my app. One contains a bunch of "slider" objects, which define a title, max, min, base value, and step for each slider. Now, I have two problems. The first is making the sliders show up in the first place. I've tried to put the following code:

```
    Sliders.find().forEach(function(slider) {
        $("#"+slider._id).slider({
            min:slider.min,
            max:slider.max,
            value:slider.base,
            step:slider.step,
            change:function(event,ui) {
                Data.update({_id:Data.findOne({slider:event.target.id})._id}, {$set:{value:ui.value}});
            }
    });
    });
```

in Meteor.startup, at the end of my client.js file, in a $(document).ready() block, and nothing seems to get it to work. When I paste it into the javascript console, however, it works. Anyways, that's my first problem.

My second problem is that whenever I slide the slider, the slider disappears. I can keep dragging the mouse around to change the value, but once I let go of the clicker, I can't change the value anymore. I've tried using the above way and calling a Meteor.method that changes it on the server side. It's the fact that I'm updating a collection that is published to the same client that makes the slider disappear. Anything short of that doesn't cause it to disappear. How should I deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: try using Template.rendered to run the code above when your template is rendered.  It sounds elements might not be in the DOM when you are looking for them with jQuery.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using the Template.preserve method? http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve

Comment: Figured it out... Basically, I had a template that had the slider div on the left and a table showing the data to the right of it. Because they were both in the same template, something went wrong with the re rendering. I surrounded the table with {{#isolate}}, and that fixed it! I'll try the preserve thing now! Thanks!

Comment: I had not tried that, but now I tried using a #constant block around the slider. That worked too (was recommended by that section of the documentation). It doesn't solve my problem of initializing the slider though... Still need to do that from the javascript console. Even putting it at the very end of my js file doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?